# How to run reports between Azure SQL and Azure AD/B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

Our project is using Azure B2C for customer identity/information and Azure SQL for transactions and such.  We need to run reports that pulls from both places (i.e. a transaction report).

What is the best way to create such reports?  Is there a pattern for this?

I could copy just the fields needed to B2C into SQL but that introduces consistency issues.

Thank you for any information!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Active Directory  for authentication with your Azure SQL Database , Not Azure AD B2C.

If you would like to use Azure AD authentication with your SQL database please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview)